# Why is this pointer incrementing by 0x10 not 0x04?

Tags: c

In the code below, when writing to the memory why does this line of code:

```
temp = ((int*) mem_allocate + i);
```

not increment the memory locations in consecutive 4 bytes? The memory locations resulted due to this are:

```
0x20000818 
0x20000828
0x20000848 
...
```

and so on.

I wanted to write the data in

```
0x20000818
0x2000081C
0x20000820 
...
```

and so on.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n = 1024; 
   int* mem_allocate;
   int loop = 0;
   int i = 0; 

   mem_allocate = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));    

   for(i=0; i<40; i++) 
   {
      int* temp; 
      temp = ((int*) mem_allocate + i);
      i=i+3; 
      *temp =0xAAAAAAAAu; 
      *mem_allocate = *temp; 
       mem_allocate = temp;

      if (i == 40)
      {
          loop = 1; 
      }
   }

   if (loop == 1) 
   {
      free(mem_allocate); 
   }
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: `0x` prefix is for hexadecimal. I would guess you want it in binary, which is `0xAAAAAAAA`.

Comment: `*temp = (int*)memory;` here are you trying to get value of memory to *temp? If so you should try `*temp =*(int*)memory; `

Comment: .. or `*temp = memory;`

Comment: `*temp = (int*)memory;` -- why are you casting `memory` to a pointer?

Comment: You need to recheck this part of the code or let us know what you need to achieve here: `int* temp; temp = ((int*) mem_allocate + i); *temp = (int*)memory; *mem_allocate = temp;   `

Comment: 0x is a hex prefix.  your line expands out to 0001000000010000 etc.  You want the binary prefix, '0b10101010'.  Or like @EugeneSh. said, 0xAAAAAAAA would work too.

Comment: There are many issues. What are you _actually_  trying to achieve?

Comment: @Wheel60 Curious, who or what text suggested casting the return value of `malloc()`, as in `mem_allocate = (int*) malloc(n*sizeof(int));` vs a more simple `mem_allocate = malloc(n*sizeof(int));` or even better `mem_allocate = malloc(sizeof *mem_allocate * n);`?

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends.

Comment: `mem_allocate` already *is* a pointer to int, thus `mem_allocate + i` is as well, any you don't need to cast again! You should stop casting everything to anything, you are just hiding errors this way or even producing them...

Comment: @K_Trenholm Note, the `0b` prefix is not standard and might not be supported by the specific compiler.

Comment: [Casting result of malloc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14879184/1312382): There are different oppinions to, I rather recommend having a look at both sides' arguments and make up a mind of your own...

Comment: Note: to generate an  alternating bit pattern for an `int`, try `int memory = (-1u)/3;`

Comment: I updated the question. and made the changes, thank you all of you.

Comment: @chux can you look at the updated question?

Comment: Why is "`ADD.W R2,R0,R1, LSL #2`" relevant to the question or the behaviour.  I suspect you are over complicating the issue by trying to answer your own question and asking about the answer your arrived at rather than just asking the much simpler and rather more obvious question.  Either way, if you are going to post assembler, use code mark-up.

Comment: The question in the title differs from the question in the body text, and is irellevant to your problem in any case.  You gave conflated at least three questions.  Surely your question is simply why the addresses increment by 16  rather then 4?

Comment: For what it is worth `ADD.W R2,R0,R1,LSL #2` means `R2 = R0 + R1 x 4`.  Shift left 2 effects a multiply by 4.  That is the `sizeof(int)` and no doubt R0 relates to `i` and is incremented by 4, so the total increment is 16.

Comment: This question could easily be fixed - I suggest you do so rather than let it get closed or down voted.

Comment: Never mind; I fixed it for you.

Comment: @Wheel60 I ask [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443140/why-is-this-pointer-incrementing-by-0x10-not-0x04?noredirect=1#comment89856385_51443140) - no response to that.  You ask for [review](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51443140/why-is-this-pointer-incrementing-by-0x10-not-0x04?noredirect=1#comment89861248_51443140) - I'll follow your lead.

Comment: @chux i'm sorry. I didn't look at the comments. and I was using stackoverflow after a while, so i didn't notice the question change. I thought the body itself is the question. My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop control variable `i` is incremented by one in the `for` loop:

```
for(i=0; i<40; i++)
```

and then by a further 3 by:

```
i=i+3;
```

So `i` is overall incremented by 4 in each iteration.  Pointer arithmetic accounts for the size of the object pointed to.  Here you are pointing to a 32 bit (4 byte) integer, and incrementing by 4 each time, so the address is incremented by 4 x 4 = 16 bytes.

You should have:

```
   for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) 
   {
      int* temp = mem_allocate + i ;
      // i=i+3; REMOVE THIS!
      ...
```

Note that the cast was unnecessary; `mem_allocate` was already an `int*` as is the type of the expression `mem_allocate + i`.

Your code is flawed in other ways, unrelated to the question you have asked - specifically the ill-advised modification of `mem_allocate` - if you modify it, any attempt to free it will be invalid.

Consider:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   const int n = 1024; 
   uint32_t* mem_allocate = malloc( n * sizeof(*mem_allocate) ) ;

   for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) 
   {
      mem_allocate[i] = 0xAAAAAAAAu; 
   }


   free( mem_allocate ) ; 

   return 0 ; 
}
```

As you can see you made a simple thing unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: I think i should replace the "i" in "int* temp = mem_allocate + i ;" with 1. and Yeah the cast is unnecessary (i changed it), thanks. and what is this instruction mean? "ADD.W R2,R0,R1, LSL #2"

Comment: @Wheel60 : Your should not change `i` to `1` - instead you should not modify `mem_allocate`!. I answered the question about the assember instruction in comments - it seemed entirely irrelevant to the question (and I removed it from the question in any case).  Keep posts to a single question and ensure the title and the question address the same issue - I fixed that too.